# How to set first and last slope of cubic spline interpolation in scipy.interpolate?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline

I have a data set containing *n* two-dimensional points (x<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>0</sub>),(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>), ... (x<sub>n-1</sub>,y<sub>n-1</sub>) where x<sub>0</sub> < x<sub>1</sub> < ... < x<sub>n-1</sub>. I want to interpolate this data set using cubic splines **with explicit slope values S<sub>BEGIN</sub> and S<sub>END</sub> set at both end points** (x<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>0</sub>) and (x<sub>n-1</sub>,y<sub>n-1</sub>). I mean, let the produced n-1 cubic functions be f<sub>0</sub>(x)=a<sub>0</sub>x<sup>3</sup>+b<sub>0</sub>x<sup>2</sup>+c<sub>0</sub>x+d<sub>0</sub>, f<sub>1</sub>, ... , f<sub>n-2</sub>, then df<sub>0</sub>/dx(x<sub>0</sub>) = S<sub>BEGIN</sub>, df<sub>n-2</sub>/dx(x<sub>n-1</sub>) = S<sub>END</sub>.

I looked in `scipy.interpolate` but can't find out how to set S<sub>BEGIN</sub> and S<sub>END</sub> to the current instance.

```
import numpy
import scipy

xi = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 100])
yi = numpy.array([3, 5, 18, 9, ... , 42])
s_begin = 2
s_end = -1

# How can I set s_begin and s_end?
f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(xi,yi,type='cubic')
```

Also, I would like to know how to get the 4(n-1) coefficients a<sub>0</sub>,b<sub>0</sub>,c<sub>0</sub>,d<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,...,d<sub>n-2</sub> of each cubic splines which should all be built in `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with `interp1d`. You can get the spline coefficients from [`splrep`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) though.

Comment: And then, you may still need to pad out the data set with appropriately chosen points to set the slopes at the end points.  Appropriate means a little algebra once to get the equations for the points needed to make aspecific slope through aspecific point.